# Get cell value using array and index formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Below array formula returns a row number, now I want to get the value from **D** column using that row number. I tried passing the row number to formula `=$D$formula` but getting error.

`{=SMALL(IF(RawData!C:C=B35&"_TC_Results.xlsxFailed",ROW(RawData!C:C)-MIN(ROW(RawData!C:C))+1),2)}`

Used: `=CONCAT("=D",SMALL(IF(RawData!C:C=B35&"_TC_Results.xlsxFailed",ROW(RawData!C:C)-MIN(ROW(RawData!C:C))+1),2))` with Alt + Shift + Enter which gives value `=D271` but not actual value.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this worked:
`=INDEX(RawData!$D:$D,SMALL(IF(RawData!C:C=B35&"_TC_Results.xlsxFailed",ROW(RawData!C:C)-MIN(ROW(RawData!C:C))+1),2),1)` adding this using Alt+Shift+Enter.

[INDEX array form](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/02/18/excel-index-function/)